# Is there a noun for a used credit token?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's possible to informally use the word *credit* to mean a token that can be exchanged for something.

Is there a noun that means a used credit token?

Comment: In such contexts, it's more common to use "concrete" nouns such as **token** or **voucher**. If the word *credit* is used, it's more likely to be as an adjective - *credit voucher, credit slip, credit note*, etc. I don't think there's a single word in common use to mean a ***used / expired** (or  otherwise invalid)* object that previously represented [a] credit. In context, a **dud** would probably be understood.

Comment: "Redeemed" applies to credit tokens that have been exchanged for something. But that is an adjective.

Comment: A *punched ticket* would be a recognizable phrase for a used credit.

Comment: How about a *depleted* token?

Comment: @GEdgar that works, but that's an adjective that modifies the noun. I was looking for a single noun to describe it, if there is one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a specific word for the purpose, but consider the following, especially *relict* and *stub*.

• *[relict](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/relict#Noun)*, “Something which, or someone who, survives or remains or is left over”
• *[remnant](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/remnant#Noun)*, “The small portion remaining of a larger thing or group”
• *[oddment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/oddment)*, “Something left over, such as a piece of cloth; a remnant or offcut”
• *[residual](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/residual#Noun)*, “A remainder left over at the end of some process”, or    *[residue](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/residue#Noun)*, “Whatever remains after something else has been removed”
• *[husk](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/husk#Noun)*, “Any form of useless, dried-up, and subsequently worthless exterior of something”
• *[stub](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stub#Noun)*, “A piece of certain paper items, designed to be torn off and kept for record or identification purposes [eg] check stub, ticket stub, payment stub”
• *[dreg](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dreg#Noun)*, “...the lowest and most worthless part of something”
and, as suggested by FumbleFingers,
• *[dud](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dud#Noun)*, “A device or machine that is useless because it does not work properly or has failed to work...” or “A lottery ticket that does not give a payout”